# Как оптимизировать поиск ключевых слов?

Tags: python, nltk

Мне нужно ускорить поиск слов в тексте. Моя текущая реализация на не самом мощном железе обрабатывает текст с ~2к символами за 10 секунд для 40 ключевых слов.

Я очищаю текст от спец. символов и знаков препинания, а также убираю служебные части речи с помощью pymorphy3, а потом по расстоянию Левенштейна ищу ключ. слова.

Тут я очищаю текст

```
def clear_text():
    cleared_text = []
    morph = pymorphy3.MorphAnalyzer()
    # Список служебных частей
    forbidden_types = {'NPRO', 'PRED', 'PREP', 'CONJ', 'PRCL', 'INTJ'}

    for word in text:
        word = word.lower()
        cleared_word = re.sub(r"[,.+–:;!?()\'\"@#№$%^&*\\/<>«»„“]", '', word)
        morph_type = morph.parse(cleared_word)[0].tag.POS
        if cleared_word != '' and morph_type not in forbidden_types:
            cleared_text.append(cleared_word)
    return cleared_text
```

Тут я ищу ключ. слова

```
def process_keywords_parts(num, text, words):
    for keyword in words:
        # Т.к. в ключ. слове может быть целое словосочетание, я сравниваю равные по кол-ву слов отрезки
        keyword_len = len(keyword.split())
        for i in range(0, len(text) - keyword_len + 1):
            slice_of_text = text[i:i + keyword_len]
            slice_of_text = ' '.join(slice_of_text)
            keyword = keyword.lower()
            dist = nltk.edit_distance(keyword, slice_of_text)
            # Проверяю расстояние, чтобы отклонение не было слишком большим 
            if dist/len(slice_of_text) <= deviation:
                print(f"{num} | {keyword} | {slice_of_text} | {str(dist)}")
```

Для оптимизации я решил использовать несколько процессов, между которыми делится множество ключ. слов.
Вот main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = get_data.get_text() # Список слов из текста
    keywords = get_data.get_keywords() # Список ключ. слов
    deviation = 0.25
    process_count = 4

    text = clear_text()
    part_piece = math.floor(len(keywords)/process_count)
    keyword_parts = []
    for i in range(process_count):
        if i + 1 == process_count:
            keyword_parts.append(keywords[ part_piece*i : ])
        else:
            keyword_parts.append(keywords[ part_piece*i : part_piece*(i+1) ])

    threads = [
                Process(target=process_keywords_parts, args=(i+1, text, keyword_parts[i]))
                for i in range(process_count-1)
            ]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    process_keywords_parts(process_count, text, keyword_parts[-1])
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно ускорить алгоритм?

Comment: 1) с какой целью вы делаете отдельный запуск процесса в конце кода ? почему он не в "общей пачке" ?   
2) `if i+1 == process_count: keyword_parts.append(keywords[ part_piece*i : ])` не нужен. срезы нормально отработают если индекс конца превысит действительный размер списка; 3) профилирование кода пробовали ? у вас может эти 10 секунд уходят на операцию вывода, а сам алгоритм отрбатывает за долисекунды

Comment: @n1tr0xs 1) Чтобы род. процесс тоже вычислял. 2) Кол-во ключ. слов может быть неделимо на кол.во процессов, поэтому последний процесс должен забирать все до конца. 3) print не съедает много времени, а вот вызов nltk.edit_distance ест львиную долю времени

Comment: Проверяли, на чем именно тромозит больше всего?

Comment: @insolor nltk.edit_distance ест процентов 90% времени. Без вызова этой функции программа работает 1-2 сек.

Comment: Неужели Левенштейн такой медленный? Есть ли что то быстрее?

Comment: Хотя честно говоря, может дело и не в Левенштейне. Его функция вызывается 25к раз

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал всё, что ест время, зарефакторить в отдельные функции, задекорированные через `@lru_cache`, часто это решает проблему. Но тут надо тщательно подойти к тому, что именно нужно вынести в функцию. Если у вас часто повторяются вызовы того же Левенштейна для одних и тех же слов, такое решение кардинально может решить проблему.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, lru_cache и вправду помог! Теперь я сравниваю не наборы слов целиком, а сравниваю слова попарно из этого набора. Тут и происходит кеширование. Ускорение в 4 раза

Comment: @ent 4 мало, у меня обычно в 10 раз ускорялось ))  А `morph.parse` у вас точно не тормозит? Я обычно его тоже кешировал. И проверьте, нужны ли вам вообще процессы. Вы знаете, что порождённый процесс (а у вас вроде именно процессы, а не потоки) копирует всю память текущего процесса? Это может очень сильно тормозить, возможно вы вообще не получаете выигрыша от процессов. А если у вас ещё и кэширование получается отдельное на каждый процесс, а не общее, то оно ещё и из-за этого может быть не настолько эффективным, как могло бы быть.

Comment: @CrazyElf Тогда пару вопросов. Стоит ли вообще использовать многопроцессорность, если я буду использовать эту программу как модуль в другой нагруженной программе? Не будут ли тогда, как вы сказали, дочерние процессы копировать память у род. процесса, и вследствие тяжелее работать? И можно ли избежать загруженности дочерних процессов, если создать их в самом начале работы, и потом загружать в них нужную информацию, например с помощью pipes?

Comment: @ent Вполне вероятно, что так и будет. Поэтому нужно тщательно продумывать архитектуру. Вы всё-таки не пробовали вообще без порождения процессов, но с кэшированием, может так даже быстрее будет?